On average, how many flips does it take to have seen the same number of heads and tails?
I was taking a quiz and this was the question. The answers were $2,4,16,32$. I think none of these are correct, if the coin is fair.
To me, this problem is essentially asking how many steps on average, does it take to return to $0$ for a symmetric $2$D random walk. The answer is $\infty$ in this case. Therefore, you expect to flip an infinite amount of times. Is this incorrect? Of course the probability of returning at some point is $1$.

Since the first toss gets you a distance $1$ away, let $E$ be the expected number of tosses to draw $1$ closer.  Then $E=.5\times 1 +.5\times 2E$ so $E=.5+E$.  Thus...

@lulu So all the answers are wrong, correct? The answer should be $\infty$ since it is a random walk.

Exactly.  $\quad$.

Note:  my simple recursion is slightly incorrect.  If the first two tosses coincide, so you are now $2$ away, your expectation from that point on is indeed $2E$ but you used one toss already, so I should have written $E=1+.5\times 2E=1+E$.  Same conclusion, of course.

@lulu, I am assuming we stop after we get equal heads and tails. Even if the mathematically correct answer is infinite times, it goes against intuition severely, no? If everyone in the world were to do this experiment with a fair coin and report their number of flips, I can't imagine how the average of everyone is going to be a large number (leaving aside infinity, due to a finite population). I would have expected most people to report a small number and a small number of people reporting bigger numbers. Sorry, this is not a rigorous argument. Just saying that something's off

You're completely correct, this is equivalent to simple symmetric random walk.
